# Eight-ball is sunk with the cue ball in the correct pocket

Tags: rules, pool

What happens if I shoot the 8 ball in the correct called pocket and it goes in along with the cue ball?

Does the answer change if the cue ball enters the pocket first, on an otherwise legal shot?